# I am getting E11000 duplicate key error collection: restauracja.tables index: reservations.user.email_1 dup key: { : null }

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my Table Collection:

```
const tableSchema = new Schema({
    number: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    seats: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    reservations: [orderSchema]
})

const Table = mongoose.model('Table', tableSchema)
```

And OrderSchema:

```
const orderSchema = new Schema({
    time: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: String
    },
    user: userSchema
})
```

And User Collection and Schema:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    phone: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    admin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
        required: true
    }
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

When i would like to create the **second** (i have no idea why first is adding) instance of table, i am getting error like in title: 
**MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: restauracja.tables index: reservations.user.email_1 dup key: { : null }**

I can create only one document in table, but i have different values in the second one.

Comment: Maybe it's impossible to create subdocument and Collection from the same schema. I don't know.

Comment: I think that, as you have tagged email property as unique, it expects different email and you probably have saved two objects with the same email which I suppose is null.

Comment: I agree but this is 2 different collections